# What does this code means? (Javascript FOR loop)

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain this code to me?
Any help will be appreciated ! Thanks!!

```
    <p id="arrayString"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var arrayString = "";
    var myArray = ["pizza", "hamburger", "chicken leg"];

        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){

            arrayString =  arrayString + myArray[i] + " ";

        }

        document.getElementById("arrayString").innerHTML = arrayString;
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand? Have you tried reading a tutorial or reference?

Comment: @Felix Sorry for the vague question, as English is not my primary language, i can get a little confused in tutorial and references.
And by the the question, i mean the entire code above.
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: So you don't know what `var arrayString` is doing? Or what `""` means? In that case I really recommend to read a tutorial first: http://eloquentjavascript.net/, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide . Explaining "everything" is too broad.

Comment: @Felix Yeah, i just don't know what "" does, the answer below has provide me an answer, and thanks for the reference, will read it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code with some comment:

```
<p id="arrayString"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var arrayString = "";  //store an empty string in the variable (the purpose is to initialize the variable in wich after(for loop) we will store the names) 

    var myArray = ["pizza", "hamburger", "chicken leg"];  //create an array with some string elements

        //foreach element in the array (the strings)...
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){

            //...add the 'i-est' element of the array to the string variable 'arrayString' and insert a space after the element
            arrayString =  arrayString + myArray[i] + " ";   
        }

        //print the string in the html element with id 'arrayString'  
        document.getElementById("arrayString").innerHTML = arrayString;
    </script>
</body>
```

The for statement iterates over the elements of the array, and in each iteration you access an element with: `myArray[i]`

Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to see how the for loop works

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but why we need to declare a variable with empty strings? And what "i-est" element means?

Comment: @Kevin: Remove it and see what happens.

Comment: check my edits above

Comment: @Moppo Many thanks to you! I understand better now!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the for loop and not the other stuff.

for loops are basically while except more organized.  `for(var i = 0;` is making the variable that is going to determine when to end the for loop.

`i < myArray.length;` is basically `while(i < myArray.length)` aka while `i` is *less* than `myArray` length it will do what's inside.

lastly, `i++;` tells the for *loop* what to do to `i` at the end of the statement to eventually make it `>=` to `myArray.length`.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to learn how to format the text.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop creates a variable `i` and executes the code within the loop as long as `i` is less than the length of `myArray`. Each time the code in the loop is executed, `i` is increased by 1.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

     arrayString =  arrayString + myArray[i] + " ";

}
```

is saying for the variable `i`, if `i < myArray.length`, execute the code `arrayString =  arrayString + myArray[i] + " ";` which adds the ith element of `myArray` to `arrayString`. For example, when the loop starts, `i=0`. So if it is true that `i < myArray.length`, then the 0th, or first, element of `myArray` is added to `arrayString` (Since array indexing begins at 0: 0 is the first element, 1 is the second, 2 is third, and so on. Then, once that is finished, the flow of control jumps back into the conditions in the for loop and executes `i++`, or "increase `i` by one". This whole process continues until the statement `i < myArray.length` is false (meaning `i >= myArray.length`, in which case the code in the for loop will be trying to add elements of the array that do not exist, like "add the 6th element of a 5 item long list").

The last line,
    document.getElementById("arrayString").innerHTML = arrayString;

gets the element in the document with the id "arrayString" and displays the text contained in `arrayString` in that element (which is the one defined at the top in paragraph tags).

Answer (score 0):

It's converting an array into a string. You could just use this, though:

```
document.getElementById("arrayString").innerHTML = myArray.join(' ');
```